# equivalent ios library for RTCMultiConnection in java script

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, swift, webrtc

I am working on webRTC iOS integration. Our Web team integrated the webrtc using RTCMultiConnection library (https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com:443/rmc3.min.js) and created the Web Application. They are setting the socket url (server url) and configuring the library objects and creating the session using the library.

Is there any equivalent library for making the connection directly from client? Or is it possible to access the .js file from swift?

Comment: Questions about off site resources are off topic on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the RTCMultiConnection-API:

- https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/blob/master/docs/ios-android.md

Above doc explains how to create a cordova-based iOS/Android application.

Everything from RTCMultiConnection-v3 is supported in cordova-apps except "Screen-Capturing". You can NOT capture your screen from any iOS/Android app.

The ONLY_Disadvantage of Cordova_based_apps is "It adds 20MB unwanted Size in the compiled iOS/Android app" .... i.e. your APK file may have 20MB minimum size.

Here is an example APK file (android-application using RTCMultiConnection v3):

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.webrtc.experiment